# How to get a summary of ressources/cost used per IAM users in AWS?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I would like to have all cost and ressources used of each IAM users.

Unfortunately, i can have only the cost of my master account. I know that i can create a organization and set OU and users AWS account to have a detail and record each events, but the ressources used by 'users' are used only for my application, i don't need to have real account, and i can't automatises all deployements if i must set password and credentials manually .

One solutions also is to create CloudTrail and Cloudwatch to record each events services but i found this 'too heavy' and i will need to calculate myself the cost because it only get the datas which are used.

I would like to know if they are exists others systemes to do that in preference with boto3.

Thank you for your responses.

Have a nice day/night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Costs are not easily associated back to "users".

AWS resources are associated with an **AWS Account**. When a user creates a resource (eg an Amazon EC2 instance), IAM will confirm that they have *permission* to launch the resource, but the resource itself is **not associated with the user who created it**.

You would need to **add tags to resources** to have more fine-grained association of costs to people/projects/departments. These tags can be used in billing reports to provide cost breakdowns.